# Django value convert by function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What is best approach to do the following operation with django rest framework?

Suppose that my server will received the following JSON data for same object:

```
// Case 1:
{
 "name":"apple",
 "category": "fruit" // fruit = 1
}
// Case 1.1:
{
 "name":"apple",
 "category": "1" // 1 for fruit
}
// Case 2: (IDEAL)
{
 "name":"apple",
 "category": 1 // 1 for fruit
}  
// Case 3:
{
 "name":"apple" // fill with default 1
}
```

My Solution now is write a special convert function for the those special field like category.

However, I have some issues for my approach

1. there exists lot of similar and this approach needs more hard-coding
2. the key value conversion pair will be updated frequently
3. this operation involves in CRUD

Comment: `"category": "fruit"` -> `"category_name":"fruit"`, `"category": "1"` -> `"category_id": "1" or 1`. `fill with default 1` -> `category = models.ForeignKey(null=False, blank=True, default=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use a dictionary for different cases ? (That is if you know that the cases will be repeated)
For example

```
{"1":1,"fruit":1,"Fruit":1,1:1,"FRUIT":1}
```

and use the category as key to get value